# Is there an identical function of MATLAB's cumtrapz in R?

Tags: r

Is there an identical function of MATLAB's cumtrapz in R?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html

Comment: Googling "Cumulative trapezoidal numerical integration in R" yields: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pracma/docs/trapz

Answer (score 5):

Yep, there is, `trapz` and `cumtrapz` are available in the `pracma` package. Just do `install.packages("pracma")` and then load it as a normal library with `library(pracma)`.

Package page: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pracma/docs/trapz

Package manual: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf

Hope it helps you!